# How to find all dates within a list of dates with Python3

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, list, python-datetime

I have list of UTC dates like so:

```
['2018-07-29T15:58:22.111904Z', '2018-07-29T15:59:22.033263Z', '2018-07-29T16:01:22.103157Z', '2018-07-30T11:41:22.032661Z', '2018-07-30T11:42:22.042215Z', '2018-07-31T12:31:21.062671Z']
```

This is not the full list. What I need is to grab all the dates that are found in the entire list.

So for this list:

```
['2018-07-29', '2018-07-30', '2018-07-31']
```

Would be returned.

How would this be accomplished with Python3?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a set comprehension with string slicing:

```
L = ['2018-07-29T15:58:22.111904Z', '2018-07-29T15:59:22.033263Z',
     '2018-07-29T16:01:22.103157Z', '2018-07-30T11:41:22.032661Z',
     '2018-07-30T11:42:22.042215Z', '2018-07-31T12:31:21.062671Z']

res = {i[:10] for i in L}
```

Result:

```
print(res)

{'2018-07-30', '2018-07-31', '2018-07-29'}
```

If you need a list and do not care about order, use `list(res)`.

If you need a *sorted* list, use `sorted(res)`.

---

If you wish to work with `datetime` objects, which is highly recommended, you should convert to `datetime` and use the `date` method. Here's one way with the 3rd party `dateutil` module:

```
from dateutil import parser

res = {parser.parse(i).date() for i in L}

print(res)

{datetime.date(2018, 7, 29),
 datetime.date(2018, 7, 30),
 datetime.date(2018, 7, 31)}
```

List conversion and sorting are possible, exactly as before.

Comment: If they're datetime objects rather than strings, the same should work without the string slicing.

Comment: A `set` only contains unique elements. It uses hashing and strings are hashable. A set comprehension is a way to create a set via an iteration.

Comment: Awesome. This is great and super helpful to know.